# Excel - Blank Cells?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I would like to return a blank cell from an if statement (`Let's call this cell SHEET2!A1`):

```
=IF(MAIN!E5=0,"",MAIN!E5)
```

However, if I call this:

```
=ISBLANK(SHEET2!A1)
```

The result is `FALSE`. I don't understand! I've tried resulting to NA() or just leaving the `""` out of the formula, but to no effect. THE CELL IS NOT BLANK - Excel tells me so.

How do I result this formula to `NOTHING?`

`BUZZYSIN`

Comment: @pnuts I need the content for a formula elsewhere in the speadsheet

Comment: It seems isblank searches for a blank cell. Change the second formula to something like "=if(SHEET2!A1="",FALSE,TRUE)".

Comment: You can return the equivalent of a blank within a formula  via a missing argument, eg `=ISBLANK(IF(1,))` returns TRUE. However this cannot be returned to a cell as the blank is converted to a zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to use VBA something like the below code

```
Sub delempty()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Rng.Cells(i,1) = "" Then
           Rng.Cells(i,1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If testing a cell containing a formula for the presence of "", you have to compare the result to "" rather than using ISBLANK:-

```
=A1=""
```

ISBLANK only works for cells which are completely empty.

Comment: So, how do I result to a blank cell?

Comment: You can't do it using a formula - only by deleting it like @pnuts says either manually or by using VBA to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to wrap the isblank formula as an If statement or else by default it will only return true or false

Try syntax similar to this:

```
=if (istext(a1), a1,"")
```

Or

```
=if(isblank (a1), a1,"")
```